# Как проверить принадлежность цвета RGB к диапазону HSB?

Tags: java, color, range, rgb, hsb

Пытаюсь проверить цвет RGB в заданном диапазоне HSB и меня не получается его найти.

```
Сам диапазон:
    Hue = 0  //оттенок
    saturation1 > 94% & saturation1 < 97%       //насыщенность 
    brightness1 > 0.55 & brightness1 < 0.6  //яркость


//Color c = new Color(BufferedImage1.getRGB(col, row));
Color c = new Color(149, 5, 5);  //для примера возьмём значение заданное вручную
int red1 = c.getRed();
int green1 = c.getGreen();
int blue1 = c.getBlue();
float[] hsb = new float[3]; 
 int r = (red1 >> 16) & 0xFF; 
int g = (green1 >> 8) & 0xFF; 
int b = (blue1  ) & 0xFF; 
Color.RGBtoHSB(r, g, b, hsb);     

float hue1 = hsb[0];
float saturation1 = hsb[1];
float brightness1 = hsb[2];

 System.out.println("Color hsb " + hue1 + ", "+ saturation1 +", "+ brightness1 + " ");  
 if ((hue1 == 0) & 
     (saturation1 > 0.94 & saturation1 < 0.97 ) &
     (brightness1 > 0.55 & brightness1 < 0.6)        ) {
      System.out.println("Color " + hue1 + ", "+ saturation1 +", "+ brightness1 + " входит в диапазон"); 
 }
```

значения HSB получаю какие то неправильные (0.6666667, 1.0, 0.019607844) хотя по сайту для RGB цвета (149,5,5) HSB соответственно должен быть равен (0,96.64,58.43)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zRrr

> java.awt.Color.getRed() возвращает в диапазоне 0-255, сдвиг не нужен